# Partial unordered string match in python?

Tags: python, partial-matches

So, I'm using a `.str.contains()` method to match my partial string. 
it does a great job, when I do this.

`sr = pd.Series(["#temp=25#soak=15#timeout=3000#controller=4310#"])`

`sr.str.contains(pat= "#temp=25#")`

Answer is `True`

But when I do this,
`sr.str.contains(pat= "#temp=25#controller=4310#")`

it gives me a `False` for the above series.

Can someone help me with the best approach for above case?

Also Imp to know, my list include multiple strings and always have different substring to match.

Comment: Is there any rules for matching? Original string should just characters? or subsequence match? or `#` is delimiter?

Comment: The rules I wanna add here is not for ordered match but for unordered match, just like the example I added in my question. The  purpose to use # is, incase if there is no # in string and substring, then  substring temp=2 also matches with string. which I don't want. by using # in string and substring I managed to match ordered substring.